# Fail to compute projected annual revenues as a multiple of last year's revenue in Excel

Tags: excel

I was trying to compute revenues for 2012-2015 that grow 10% per year off a base level of 300 in 2011, by using the formula =previous*(1+growth). I have named B2 "growth" and B7 "previous" as instructed in my textbook.

But as I finished typing the formula in B7 and dragged down to B10, all the values from B7 to B10 became 0. What can I do to make this formula work? Appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvjlM.png

Comment: I assume that if you press one of the boxes that turned into 0 then it would show B3 and B8 or higher, correct?

Comment: http://www.notjustnumbers.co.uk/2011/05/excel-tip-dollar-sign-in-formula-fixing.html

Comment: Can you post some of the data and exact formulas from the cells so that we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

Change the formula to:

```
=previous*(1+$growth)
```

This should fix  your issue.